# Continuous Integration and Testing Tools for projects which use PHP, Javascript, jQuery, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, continuous-integration, teamcity, php-ci

I have base project with I use to setup websites with CMS. It has more and more options and it's more and more difficult to maintain the code of it. I plan to use some Continuous Integration for it and finally start adding tests. This system is written in PHP with MySQL database and uses libraries like jQuery and AngularJS.

I'm thinking about tools like below:

- testing Tools:

  - PHP: PHPUnit
  - Javascript / jQuery / AngularJS: Jasmine
  - Also Selenium for frontend testing and in PHPUnit (Selenium Webdriver)
- Subversion (it has to be)
- CI: PHP-CI

I want to ask if these choices are good? Maybe TeamCity will be better?
A someone has experience with PHP / Javascript projects and could give some advice.

Comment: If this question is duplicated, give me some links for answers, because I didn't found complex answer.

Comment: TeamCity can build and deploy any kind of application. And judging by your post, it will be a pain to setup using anything because it's a heck of a lot easier to start off with a deployment pipeline and writing tests. Best wishes to you.